# Where i should install a bag?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody. I downloaded a bag from this site https://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=basic_localization_stage.bag, but i don't know where i should install this bag. I save it in downloades. Maybe it's a stupid question, but please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360619/where-i-should-install-a-bag?/) by [felior](https://answers.ros.org/users/58832/felior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nothing stupid about this.

> i don't know where i should install this bag.

You don't *install* `.bag` files. They are essentially data files, which contain data you can use with other programs or tools.

So any place on your computer would be OK, as long as the tools/programs you'd like to use with the file can access it.

> I save it in downloades.

that would be an OK place.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felior](https://answers.ros.org/users/58832/felior/) on 2020-08-31**:
Thank you, dude. You've been very helpful))))